# Riverpod passing ref.watch as argument

Tags: flutter, riverpod

In Riverpod, I can pass the ref.read and it is "Reader" type.

How to pass "ref.watch" and what will be its type ?
I can't figure that out from the source code.

Is it bad practice to pass "ref.watch" ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you shouldn't have to pass `ref.watch`, you must be misunderstanding something. Can you provide more details about where you want to use `ref.watch` ?

Comment: Hi. You are right. I changed my code. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a good practice to pass the ref.watch as you question. The purpose of ref.watch is to 'watch' for changing at the state and re-build, so, normally the ref.watch goes inside the build of the widgets (ConsumerWidgets).

All in all, I'm trying to figure why you need to pass it.

I figure you need such solution for reading other providers, correct?

You can pass only the ref as an argument to allow the class to read the other providers. Passing the ref, you can create the ref.watch and the ref.read, but, take care where to use the ref.watch because it is not recommended to use it inside the provider itself. Take a look to the Riverpod detailed documentation [here](https://riverpod.dev/)

For example, if you create a provider to hold the whole logic of the app, you can create a class that get the ref value from the provider as following:

```dart
final createController = Provider((ref) => CreateProvider(ref));

class CreateProvider {

    CreateProvider(this.ref) {
        _init();
    }

    //Init to initialize values
    _init() async {

    }

    //Ref to access other providers
    final Ref ref;

}
```

Having the ref, you can access other providers registered at the provider Scope.